# "Canon RGB" color space *shift* to broadcast range with FFMPEG

Tags: ffmpeg, canon, colorspace, broadcast, avisynth

for a noprofit project I do shoot with (up to 5x) Canon HF100 camera(s) but, as stated in [this interesting artile](http://nerdfever.com/video-editing-for-scientific-analysis/), it genetates a "custom RGB range" (16-255) files.

Thanks to [this cool repository](https://github.com/dericed/ffmpeg-mpeg2video-clipping) I've generated this GIF of 10s of source video:

http://www.forart.it/_priv/cultura/HF100_measurement.gif (33 Mb, so can't post. Click to watch)

It graphically shows how recorded video exceed the broadcast range.

The question is: how to "shift down" everything (and constrain inside broadcast range, of course) in order to preserve the maximum possible color quality ?

(note: someone already suggested me to use " *Levels(0, 16, 255, 16, 235, coring=false)* " in AviSynth but, if possible, I want to do it only with FFMPEG)

Thanks in advance to anyone that can/will help.

Marco

Comment: Can be done with lut filters.

Comment: Well, I've already asked @ Doom9 forums and here is the response: https://forum.doom9.org/showthread.php?p=1902399

Comment: Can you share a sample video from HF100?

Comment: Of course, here's an untouched shooting as downloaded from the camera: https://clicknupload.co/0ooaljx1oqi1

Comment: Here's another interesting discussion - I'm partecipating in too - about FFMPEG's color "management": https://forum.videohelp.com/threads/395939-ffmpeg-Color-Range/

Comment: Ok, chris319 (@ videohelp.com 3ad) suggested this parameters: -vf lutrgb='r=clip(val,30,223)',lutrgb='g=clip(val,30,223)',lutrgb='b=clip(val,30,223)'

Comment: Ok, so your video is YUV, not RGB.And clip will squish the values beyond the clip ranges. You should remap them. I'll post an answer shortly.

Answer (score 1):

You can use the geq filter to remap the pixel value ranges.

```
ffmpeg
 -i input
 -vf "geq=lum='(p(X,Y)-16)/(255-16)*(235-16)+16':cb='(p(X,Y)-16)/(255-16)*(240-16)+16'"
 -c:v libx264 -c:a copy out.mp4
```

The geq filter rescales the input luma from 16-255 to 16-235, and both the input chroma from 16-255 to 16-240, which is  the legal range for broadcast 8-bit signals.

Comment: Thank you very mutch for your help ! Another question: is there a way to "legalize" any source level to broadcast level ? In other words: can FFMPEG probe source file(s) level before remap to broadcast ?